# Cef Sharp memory usage issue and deallocation problem

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Cef Sharp is consuming a large amount of virtual memory on my system, and it does not deallocate memory even after calling the chromiumWebBrowser dispose and Cef.Shutdown() function.

I can see this issue on Cef_Demo_Application as well by Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64.
Always its taking almost 35GB virtual memory.

as of now i am using version 98.1.210.0, i have tried with latest version as well in latest version it is taking more than 70GB virtual memory.

I have tried various solutions, such as disabling cache,disable-gpu-process and enabling multi-threaded message loop, but none of them have solved the issue.
please suggest a solution or workaround.

**Initilization code**

```
mySettings = new CefSettings
{
LogFile = aLogPath + "\\Cef.log",
AcceptLanguageList = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name,
IgnoreCertificateErrors = true, // useless
WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true, // useless
PersistSessionCookies = false, // useless
PersistUserPreferences = false, // useless    
};

mySettings.CachePath = aLogPath;
mySettings.JavascriptFlags = "false";
mySettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-process", "1");
mySettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-javascript", "1");
mySettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("process-per-site", "1");
mySettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("process-per-tab");
// Here i can see 6 GB VM
if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
{
 Cef.Initialize(mySettings);                
 DebugTrace.Items.Add($"After Cef Initalize VM = { GetGB() } GB");
 mychromiumWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
 mychromiumWebBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
 mychromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings.Javascript = CefState.Disabled;
 mychromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings.LocalStorage = CefState.Disabled;
 mychromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings.Plugins = CefState.Disabled;
 mychromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings.LocalStorage = CefState.Disabled;

 // Here i can see 39 GB virtual memory allocated
}
```

**Dispose code**

```
mychromiumWebBrowser.Dispose();
mychromiumWebBrowser = null;
Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().DeleteCookies();
mySettings.Dispose();
Cef.Shutdown();
GC.Collect();
// here also i can see 39GB virtual memory allocated
```

Comment: Can you show some code? From your description, it's very hard to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4477